# Issues with transforming data from NAD 1983 to WGS84 in R using sf / rgdal packages

Tags: r, transform, coordinate-systems, r-sf, wgs84

I have tried to transform my benthic habitat data into WGS 84 using R, in order to use in arcMap so that it will fit with the rest of my data (seamounts, landpolygons, point data etc). The original data is in the coordinate system NAD 1983. Unfortunately, when inputting to to arcMap the same misalignment issues occur that I have tried to rectify within arc.

Here is the code I used

```
africanbanks_wgs84 <- st_transform(africanbanks, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
  st_crs(africanbanks_wgs84)
st_write(africanbanks_wgs84, "africanbanks_wgs84", driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is please? and if so, I look forward to reading your solution!

Comment: What errors do you get? What are the messages? In the `st_write` do you need to write it as "africanbanks_wgs84.shp"?

Comment: @william3031 There were no errors, it appears to have done something. I exported the data but when I add to arcMap the issue arises. The transformation has not worked.

Comment: What happens when you put it in to Arcmap though? Does it not show up? Does it show an error?

Comment: It shows up, no error message. All that happens is that it is still not aligned with the land polygon data (WGS84 when downloaded) and my other point data (also in WGS84). I tried deleting the .prj file from the shapefile to see if that worked (having no projection maybe I could then assign one) this did not work either.